# Android: WiFi Direct connection left open (surviving) even after the app is killed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, wifi-direct

I'm trying to develop a wireless communication protocol for my future apps, and I'm currently interested in WiFi Direct: I'm under the impression that this method can both provide the fastest connection AND the most powerful signal, outclassing Bluetooth in both fields.

While using the (official?) example code provided by Google at this address
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo

I found something that feels really off to me: if two devices connects via WiFi Direct but one (or even both) of them closes the app, the connection on the server side "stays on" until the "client" phone is shut down or it's "out of reach".
This is just plain weird, to me.
I know that by invoking removeGroup() and by checking if any socket was left open I could eventually create a disconnect() method, but it's also true that in Android the only non-killable method is onpause(), so basically I'm left with two options here:

1. having a connection that survives my app;
2. closing any existing connection every time I do something as simple as "rotating my phone between landscape and portrait mode".

...Am I missimg something here?

Answer (score 0):

3. handling orientation change and other changes so you don't restart you activity and disconnect when needed (onStop: "*the app should release or adjust resources that are not needed while the app is not visible to the user.*")

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle